# Can't Secure Hosted Blazor Webassembly File Download

Tags: blazor-server-side, middleware, static-files

I have a hosted blazor web assembly app where I want to secure file downloads so that only a user with the correct role / permissions can download a file from the folder. I do not want an anonymous user to be able to download any files from this folder.
The files are located in a folder named `Uploads` in the server / api project, so they are not in the `wwwroot` folder.

The server pipeline looks like:

```
...
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Uploads")),
    RequestPath = "/SellerFiles"
});

//app.Map("", appBuilder =>
//{
//    appBuilder.UseFilter();

//    appBuilder.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
//    {
//        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider($@"{Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Uploads")}"),
//        RequestPath = new PathString("/SellerFiles"), //empty, because root path is in Map now
//        EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false
//    }); 
//});

app.MapControllers();
...
```

`UseFilters` looks like

```
public class FilterMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public FilterMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        List<Claim> claims = httpContext.User.Claims.ToList();

        await _next(httpContext);
        //if (true)
        //{
        //    //proceed serving files
        //    await _next(httpContext);
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    //return you custom response
        //    await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Forbidden");
        //}
    }
}

public static class FilterMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseFilter(this IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
    {
        return applicationBuilder.UseMiddleware<FilterMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

When a user requests a file from `https://mywebsite.com/SellerFiles/...`, I want to serve the file if they are authenticated, but not if they are anonymous.

I tried implementing the commented code `app.Map UseFileServer`, but I wasn't able to configure it correctly. I played around with it alot and I was not able to get it to hit a breakpoint in `public async Task InvokeAsync` when I made a request to `/SellerFiles`.

Right now, an authenticated user can download a file from the `Uploads` folder by making a call to `/SellerFiles`, but so can an anonymous user.

How can I properly protect the files?

**Edit**
I think I found the problem, but I am not quite there yet. I followed the guidance here: [Microsoft Link to Static File Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-8.0#static-file-authorization)

I set the authorization fallback policy, and it works well. I had to make some controller methods AllowAnonymous. So now the Uploads folder should require authorization, but I can still download files when not logged in.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore(options =>
{    
    var type = typeof(Permissions);

    foreach (var permission in type.GetFields())
    {
        options.AddPolicy(
            permission.GetValue(null)?.ToString() ?? "",
            policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireAssertion(
                context => context.User.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == "Permissions" && claim.Value == permission.GetValue(null)?.ToString())));
    }

    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();

});
```

```
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
else
{
    app.UseResponseCompression();
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors("AllowAll");

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
app.MapHangfireDashboard();
app.MapHub<SignalR>("/chathub");


using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{   
    var jobService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IScheduleJobs>();
    jobService.Run();
    //do your stuff....
}

var options = new DashboardOptions
{
    Authorization = new IDashboardAuthorizationFilter[]
        {
            new HangfireDashboardJwtAuthorizationFilter(tokenValidationParameters, "Administrator")
        }
};
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", options);

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Uploads")),
    RequestPath = "/SellerFiles"
});

app.Run();
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved my issue and wanted to show the solution. I ended up calling an API endpoint and streaming the file back to the client. Then I use a simple Javascript function to create an `A tag` and invoke the download. The user chooses where to save the file. Also, I removed all of the modifications I had made to Program.cs.

This is my razor.cs code which is invoked by the user clicking the download button.

```
protected async Task DownloadFile(CartViewModel cartViewModel)
{
    FileDownload fileDownload = new FileDownload()
    {
        OrderId = cartViewModel.OrderId,
        SellerId = cartViewModel.Product?.SellerId,
        ZipFileName = cartViewModel.Product?.ZipFileName
    };

    if(OrderService != null)
    {
        bool response = await OrderService.DownloadFileStream(fileDownload, $"{ApiEndpoints.File}/download/{cartViewModel.Product?.SellerId}/{cartViewModel.OrderId}", JSruntime);

        if (response)
        {
            SnackbarService?.Add("File Downloaded Successfully", Severity.Success);
        }
        else
        {
            SnackbarService?.Add("Problem Downloading File", Severity.Error);
        }
    }            
}
```

This is my OrderService.DownloadFileStream method.

```
public async Task<bool> DownloadFileStream(FileDownload model, string endPoint, IJSRuntime JSruntime)
{
    try
    {
        var user = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(model);
        var requestContent = new StringContent(user, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        if (!await GetBearerToken())
        {
            return false;
        }

        Stream stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(endPoint);


        byte[] bytes;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
        string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        await JSruntime.InvokeAsync<object>("saveAsFile", model.ZipFileName, base64);


    }
    catch (ApiException exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This is my controller endpoint.

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Policy = Permissions.PurchaseProducts)]
[Route("download/{SellerId}/{OrderId:int}")]
public async Task<MemoryStream> Get([FromRoute] string SellerId, [FromRoute] int OrderId)
{
    string filePath = string.Empty;

    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@$"Uploads\{SellerId}\{OrderId}\");            

    FileInfo[] files = d.GetFiles();

    // There should only be 1 file in this folder
    foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in files)
    {
        if (fileInfo.Extension.ToLower().Trim() == ".zip")
        {
            filePath = @$"Uploads\{SellerId}\{OrderId}\{fileInfo.Name}";
        }
    }

    if(filePath == string.Empty)
    {
        return new MemoryStream();
    }
    
    //converting Pdf file into bytes array
    var dataBytes = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filePath);
    //adding bytes to memory stream
    var dataStream = new MemoryStream(dataBytes);

    return dataStream;
}
```

And this is the Javascript function.

```
function saveAsFile(filename, bytesBase64) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = filename;
    link.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + bytesBase64;
    document.body.appendChild(link); // Needed for Firefox
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

Since the files are in an Uploads folder outside of wwwroot, users cannot get to `https://mywebsite.com/Uploads` or any subfolders, so my files are protected. I plan to add checks in the controller endpoint to ensure that the user really is authorized to download the file, i.e., they paid for it.